# Using performSelector: to access BOOL property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, declared-property

I am using `performSelector:`, which returns an `id` object, to call several other methods. The return type of those methods can actually be either be a `BOOL`, `int`, `NSDate` or any other kind of object.

How can I figure out whether the object returned from `performSelector:` is a `BOOL` or not?
I tried converting it to a `NSNumber` and such, but this crashes if the object is not a `BOOL`.

I have a class with attributes such as these:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString* A;
@property(assign,nonatomic) BOOL B;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSArray* C;
@property(assign,nonatomic) int64_t D;
```

This class is generated by a framework, so I cannot change it. But I want to loop over `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` to call each attribute and retrieve the data. However, as you can see, the return type can vary and I need to adjust to that.

I am doing something similar to:

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(@"A");
id obj = [object performSelector:s];
//check if obj is BOOL
//do something with obj
```

Comment: Please include some code. And note that BOOL and int are _not_ objects.

Comment: sounds like a flaw in the design.

Comment: Can you show us how you created the BOOL and int in the function? You shouldn't return a BOOL or int as an id you see, you need to wrap in an NSNumber

Comment: Yeah, better design needed..

Comment: I agree that it is also a design issue, but I am working with a generated class from a framework here. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Are you saying that ahead of time that you do not know that "B" will return a BOOL and that "D" will return an int64_t????

Comment: For B and D you need to convert them to NSNumber and return that; though you'd probably have difficulty determining if the stored value is a bool or an int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you need to do is obtain the values of various properties, use key-value coding, which automatically wraps scalar types such as `int` and `BOOL` in instances of `NSNumber`. So all you would need would be a line like the following:

```
id value = [object valueForKey:@"somePropertyName"];
```

Otherwise, you could check ahead of time for the return type by calling `methodSignatureForSelector:` on the target object, but that seems like a bunch of unnecessary work given the situation you described.

Comment: Moreover, you _can't_ use `performSelector:` for a non-object return type. As [its docs say:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBGHFG) "For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation."

Comment: @JoshCaswell *Can't* might be too strong a word, as it's possible to use `performSelector:` to invoke a method that returns a scalar value and then cast the result to the appropriate type, but it's clearly not intended for that use, so in general you *shouldn't*.

Comment: Such a cast is not guaranteed to get you the value you expect (depending on ABI): http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/288663-bool-returned-via-performselctor-not-bool-on-64-bit-system.html, http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/320/abusing-objective-c-with-class (see especially the link to Greg Parker's post) and won't work at all for floats or structs.

Comment: Right, which is why you really, really *shouldn't*.  ;-)